# Can't convert symbol to integer error with rails simple_form nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, nested-forms

I've seen many similar questions, and looked at the answers, but nothing seems to be helping me and I've been working on this for a while now. The error is 'Can't convert symbol into integer'. My goal is to be able to create multiple sub_groups for each race. I'm just starting with trying to create one for the time being. Here's the relevant code...

** **UPDATE** **

**VIEW**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@race, :url => form_path, :method => form_method, :html => { :class =>  
'form-horizontal form-compressed' }) do |f| %>

<fieldset>
<%= f.simple_fields_for :sub_groups do |g| %>
  <%= g.input :name, requred: false %>
  <%= g.collection_radio_buttons :discount_type,
                                 [['dollars', '$'], ['percent', '%']], :first, :last %>
  <%= g.input :discount_amount, :as => :integer, required: false %>
<% end %>
<hr/>
```

** RACE MODEL**

```
class Race < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :sub_groups
accepts_nested_attributes_for :sub_groups
attr_accessible :sub_groups_attributes
```

** SUB_GROUP MODEL **

```
class SubGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :race
  has_many :race_users

  attr_accessible :discount_amount, :discount_type, :display_results, :name
end
```

**PARAMS**
after my code update...

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",    
"authenticity_token"=>"VihBL4TDT/Lte4YBji/4fp4XvOri1UgUZ8B33wQuCko=", "race"=>
{"sub_group"=>{"name"=>"dfd", "discount_type"=>"dollars", "discount_amount"=>"2"}},  
"commit"=>"Next", "wizard"=>"2", "id"=>"13-test5"}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
class RacesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @race = Race.new
    @sub_groups = @race.sub_groups.build
    @wizard_step = -1
    @wizard_step_name = Race.wizard_step_name_from_id @wizard_step
    @wizard_mode = true
    render :layout => "race_wizard"
  end
def update
  @race = Race.find params[:id]
  @wizard_step = params[:wizard].to_i + 1
  @race.wizard_step = @wizard_step
  @race.update_attributes(params[:race])
end
```

So I took advice from answer 1, and switched to using :sub_groups in the view. Now I have a new problem, which is the sub-group fields don't show up at all, despite the fact that I built a sub_groups thing in the #new method.
I'm really stumped on how I can make this happen. This is driving me bonkers. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: We'll need more details. When exactly is this error been thrown - I assume it is after submission. If so, could you please paste your controller code? Aslo pasting error itself together with a stack would help a lot.

Comment: I updated with more details about controller actions. Also changed some things based on first answer. And yes, the problem was happening after submission. But now I have a new problem, which is the fields don't show up at all. I think I'm building a sub-groups property when the #new method gets hit, but maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Ok, let's debug: add `<%= (f.object && f.object.sub_groups.count).inspect %>` just above `simple_fields_for` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way fields_for works is that if you supply a symbol it checks whether your model respond to `{given_symbol}_attributes=`. If it does the name of sub-fields is `{given symbol}_attributes`, otherwise just `{given_symbol}`.

What you need is to add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :sub_groups` to your Race model. This methods will create a default setter `sub_groups_attributes=`, which will make `fields_for :sub_groups` to generate fields with name `sub_groups_attributes`.

You can also write your own `sub_groups_attributes=` method, but you need to be sure you know what you're doing there as it might be a little tricky to debug.

Note, that `fields_to :sub_groups` won't display fields if there are no sub_group associated with given object - you will need to build one in your controller first.

Comment: Thanks for this. That cleared some things up about how {symbol}_attributes works, and I made changes based on what you said, but I'm running into a new problem. You'll see in the params that even though I changed fields_for to use sub_groups, and I added accepts_nested_attributes_for, and have the attr_accessible all set properly for sub_groups, the params still come back as just "sub_group", and not "sub_group_attributes". Also, now the sub_group fields aren't showing up at all. But maybe that's an ereror with how I'm building them in the #new method?

Comment: So, I ended up realizing that your answer was right, and then I thought I was building a sub_group, but I was only doing that on the #new action. I needed to do it on the #edit action. So I just put did... race.sub_groups.build on my #edit action, and all is well.